# Method to find object by ID with firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Well, I want to create this method, but since you're not able to return from listener's methods, I just can't figure it out a way to give the user when firebase finds it:

```
public static User findByID(@NonNegative final int id) {
    getDatabase().orderByChild("id")
            .equalTo(id)
            .limitToFirst(1)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);    // this one must be returned
                }

                @Override public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
                @Override public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
                @Override public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
                @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
}
```

Creating a variable to receive value and return doesn't work as well, since firebase takes a bit long to find the user.

Comment: You cannot return asynchronous objects, so you need to pass in an `EventListener` to the function that you made, and then call it when you get the user.

Comment: What you're trying to do is very similar to what I used to do when starting out with Firebase – essentially trying to create synchronous methods to retrieve data (similar to how you might do with a traditional database). Unfortunately, that's just not the way Firebase works (sadly), the asynchronous nature of Firebase is inherent to how it works and you need to build your app's behavior around that which can be a bit cumbersome at times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data retrieval is asynchronous in Firebase, so you cannot *return*. I think there are two ways to overcome the problem you are facing.

**First Way**

If data should be returned somewhere in the same class in which `findById()` exists, then you can do as follows:

```
class A {

    private TextView nameTextView;

    ...

    public void findById(@NonNegative int id) {
        userRef().orderByChild("id")
            .equalTo(id)
            .limitToFirst(1)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    onUserRetrieved(user);
                }
                ...
            });
    }

    private void onUserRetrived(User user) {
        // Now you can do whatever you want with the "user"
        // For instance, update name field in the layout...
        nameTextView.setText(user.getName);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Second Way**

If you need to notify an instance of another class, you can pass a listener to the function as parameter and then call a method in that listener as a way of notifying the caller. An example caller would look like as follows:

```
class Caller {

    ...

    private void someFunction() {
        ...
        String userId = 1; // Get user id somehow
        DatabaseUtil.findUserById(userId, new DatabaseUtil.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onUserRetrieved(User user) {
                // Now you can do whatever you want with the "user"
            }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

whereas your static function may reside in a class as follows:

```
class DatabaseUtil {

    public static void findUserById(@NonNegative int id, Listener listener) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getreference("user")
            .orderByChild("id")
            .equalTo(id)
            .limitToFirst(1)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    listener.onUserRetrieved(user);
                }
                ...
            });
    }

    interface Listener {
        void onUserRetrieved(User user);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is kind of abstract to me. Can you make an example?

Comment: Where do you plan on using your `findById` method?

Comment: Let's consider I've got user's ID and want to get his name to show on ProfileActivity.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Second way works just fine. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: hi @mehmad there is any way to query  the data based on selected id's. using loop